# How to pass parameters to a class after restarting it with os.execl()?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

I'm developing a software with pyqt5 and matplotlib, and want to change matplotlib.style after the program has started. I know that, it cannot be done just using the command style.use('new_style') after the software has started.

So that, I'm trying to do it by putting a button that is going to change a parameter passed to the main class, then restart the program and finally change the style.

```
# Main Class
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, mode, parent=None):
'''mode is the parameter used to change the style'''

        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Application")
        QApplication.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create('Fusion'))
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('../_img/icon.png'))
        self.isDirectlyClose = False
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

'''where the style is changed'''
        if mode == 'Light': style.use('bmh')
        else: style.use('dark_background')

'''the method where I want to make the "magic"'''
    def changeMode(self):
        python = sys.executable
        os.execl(python, python, *sys.argv)

'''other methods...'''



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    sys._excepthook = sys.excepthook

'''I want to change the parameter passed here after the method changeMode is called'''
    main = Window('Light')
    main.showMaximized()
    #main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you refer to `os.environ.get()` in setting your value...

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    sys._excepthook = sys.excepthook
    main = Window(os.environ.get('windowMode', 'Light'))
    main.showMaximized()
```

...then you can modify it before re-exec'ing yourself:

```
    def changeMode(self):
        currentWindowMode = os.environ.get('windowMode', 'Light')
        os.environ['windowMode'] = 'Dark' if (currentWindowMode == 'Light') else 'Light'
        python = sys.executable
        os.execl(python, python, *sys.argv)
```